# why dont show me the data ? WINRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-store

im try to do a simple excercise, but, when i test the first part (show person data) dont show me nothing into UI.

I checked the bindings and I guess are okay, too, I do a debug in the click event of the button and get all the data, but the UI does not show me anything.

all proyect here: [Less_300kb](http://sdrv.ms/17WwAWn) or:

```
public class Persona: BindableBase
{
    private string _nombre;
    public string Nombre
    {
        get { return _nombre; }
        set { _nombre = value;
              SetProperty(ref _nombre, value);}
    }

    private string _apellido;
    public string Apellido
    {
        get { return _apellido; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _apellido, value); }
    }

    private int _cedula;
    public int Cedula
    {
        get { return _cedula; }
        set { _cedula = value;
              SetProperty(ref _cedula, value);}
    }

    private string _profesion;
    public string Profesion
    {
        get { return _profesion; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _profesion, value); }
    }
}
```

the second class

```
public class GrupoPersonas
{
    public string Profesion { get; set; }
    public List<Persona> ListaPersonas { get; set; }
}
```

the Last class

```
public class DataSourcePersonas
{
    //public List<Persona> ListaPersonas { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Persona> ListaPersonas { get; set; }

    public void CrearLista()
    {
        var listaPivote = new ObservableCollection<Persona>() 
            {
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Ingeniero",Apellido="Ruiz Pacheco",Nombre="Juan Carlos"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Médico",   Apellido="Gonzalez Ramírez",     Nombre="Miguel"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Analista", Apellido="Ramirez",       Nombre="Angel"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Enfermero",Apellido="Aldana",        Nombre="Cesar"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Conductor",Apellido="Echeverry",    Nombre="Andres"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Piloto",   Apellido="Coronel",      Nombre="David"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Capitán",  Apellido="Baracaldo",         Nombre="Alejandro"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Biólogo",  Apellido="Palacios",      Nombre="Mauricio"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Físico",   Apellido="Botía",         Nombre="Oscar"},
            new Persona(){ Profesion="Astrónomo",Apellido="Heldford",     Nombre="Axwell"}
            };

        Random genCedula = new Random();
        var listaFull = from persona in listaPivote
                        from persona2 in listaPivote
                        from persona3 in listaPivote
                        select new Persona()
                        {
                            Cedula = (int)(genCedula.NextDouble() * 999999999),
                            Nombre = persona.Nombre,
                            Apellido = persona2.Apellido,
                            Profesion = persona3.Profesion
                        };

        //ListaPersonas = new List<Persona>(listaFull);
        ListaPersonas = new ObservableCollection<Persona>(listaFull);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<GrupoPersonas> ListaPersonasAgrupada { get; set; }
    public void CrearGrupo()
    {
        var lista = from persona in ListaPersonas
                    group persona by persona.Profesion into grupo
                    select new GrupoPersonas()
                    {
                        Profesion = grupo.Key,
                        ListaPersonas = grupo.ToList()
                    };
        ListaPersonasAgrupada = new ObservableCollection<GrupoPersonas>(lista);
    }

}
```

the xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <data:DataSourcePersonas x:Key="DataSourcePersonas"
                             x:Name="DataSourcePersonas"></data:DataSourcePersonas>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CvsGruposPersonas" x:Name="CvsGruposPersonas" IsSourceGrouped="True"
                          Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSourcePersonas}, Path=ListaPersonasAgrupada}"
                          ItemsPath="ListaPersonas"></CollectionViewSource>
</Page.Resources>


GridView x:Name="gvGroup" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataSourcePersonas}, Path=ListaPersonas}" 
              Margin="10,113,10,10">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource apptile}">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonName}"       Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonName}"       Text="{Binding Apellido}"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonCedula}"     Text="{Binding Cedula}"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PersonProfession}" Text="{Binding Profesion}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

MainPage

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        DataSourcePersonas.CrearLista();
        DataSourcePersonas.CrearGrupo();

        gvGroup.UpdateLayout();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what's happening is your `GridView` is getting the `ListaPersonasAgrupada`, and then you are changing it, but your `GridView` doesn't know that it was changed.

You need to have your `ViewModel` tell your `GridView` that `ListaPersonasAgrupada` has changed. You can do this with `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Or, if you're using MvvmLight, you can use RaisePropertyChanged.

The other option is to re-set the ItemsSource of the GridView, but that will break the binding.

Comment: yes!, you're right, in my ViewModel Class implemented the class inheritance BindableBase (implements InotifyPropertyChanged), and ListaPersonas property I added SetProperty:                  `private ObservableCollection<Persona> _ListaPersonas;

        public ObservableCollection<Persona> ListaPersonas
        {
            get { return _ListaPersonas; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _ListaPersonas, value); }
        }`                                                              Works Perfectly! :) Thnks!